# Can't activate plugin

Tags: plugins

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-content\themes\Total\functions.php on line 283

Answer (score 1):

Open this file

`C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-content\themes\Total\functions.php`

go to on line `283` and check how you have added add_action function.

It must be like this.

```
add_action('tag','function_callback' );
```

`add_action` is a  function which allows you to attach a function to an action hook and it must not be string eg. `'add_action'`

Please read document about add_action http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Answer (score 0):

This error often occurs with syntax errors like missing brackets in the code. In your case probably in the lines preceding the `add_action` call. Check the syntax there or post the previous code block here please.